# MySQL joining 2 tables Wrong output..the value multiply

Tags: mysql

I have a major problem for my Capstone project. I'm joining 2 tables from my database but the output is [image: This is the output there is data anomaly]

MY Query: select Distinct  tbl_attendance_in.time_in as time_in,tbl_attendance_out.time_in as time_out from tbl_attendance_in join tbl_attendance_out on tbl_attendance_in.user_id=tbl_attendance_out.user_id where tbl_attendance_in.user_id=4 AND tbl_attendance_out.user_id=4;

I've already tried all sorts of joining like inner right,outer right,inner join but still no luck.

[image: The value of user_id=4 in my tbl_attendance_in is only]

[image: Also same for my tbl_attendance_out only two values but the output is]

[image: Output]

Comment: I need some context here. What is the result that you want to get? All the `time_in` and `time_out` from a specific user or ... ?

Comment: specific user sir for their time_in and and  alias only (time_out). both tables have 2 values only but the output there's 4
time in | Timeout
value1 | Value1
value2 | Value2
value1 | Value1
value2 | Value2

it's repeating. Select distinct is not working also T_T

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63948182/edit) and post your codes in text, not images

Comment: Since you are joining on user id only and all 4 records in the two tables have the same user id, sql produces a combination of the records => 2x2 records will be in the resultset. You need to define additional fields to join on if you want to narrow down the number of matches.

Comment: How to that sir shadow?

Comment: For example, you could get the time_in and time_out of the same day or something like that. I don't see what you're trying to accomplish with that join.

Comment: What MariaDB version are you using?

Comment: version 10.3.16

Comment: sir Victor i'm trying to display the attendance of specific user and count the total attendance of user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can make a sub-query for both of the tables first and generate a row number based on the `time_in` column ordering. Then you do a `LEFT JOIN` between those two. Something like this example query below:

```
SELECT A.user_id,A.time_in,B.time_in AS 'time_out' FROM
/*the first sub-query is for time in table*/
   (SELECT user_id, time_in,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time_in) AS RowN 
    FROM tbl_attendance_in WHERE user_id=4) A 
LEFT JOIN
/*the second sub-query is for time out table*/
   (SELECT user_id, time_in,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time_in) AS RowN 
    FROM tbl_attendance_out WHERE user_id=4) B
ON A.User_id=B.User_id AND A.RowN=B.RowN;
```

I'm using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` function to generate a running number for each of the row data then using it in the `ON` for the `LEFT JOIN`. Although this can give you the result for your current example, it might not be the best solution considering other factors like date of the time_in and time_out must match, or if there's any duplicate (but valid) timestamp in one of the table.

Another that you can consider is using `UNION ALL`. Example below:

```
SELECT 'IN' AS Opr, user_id, time_in AS records,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time_in) AS RowN 
FROM tbl_attendance_in WHERE user_id=4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'OUT' AS Opr, user_id, time_in AS records,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time_in) AS RowN 
FROM tbl_attendance_out WHERE user_id=4 order by RowN, records;
```

This also uses `ROW_NUMBER()` function for the ordering and I added `Opr` column to indicate which operation (or table) its coming from.

Maybe you can try both and see if you can use it. If you have other concern, just edit your question and add more details.

To fiddle around: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=087e4a7cabb5e50090639b5f3435aaa7

Comment: Thank you sir. i've tried 3 values in time in and only 2 values in time_out and that's the output sir
.
The output in codeigniter
Time_in 
value1     
value2
Time_out

value1
value2

Answer (score 0):

If it multiplies the data then you can use **group by** at the end of your query.

```
select Distinct tbl_attendance_in.time_in as time_in,tbl_attendance_out.time_in as time_out from tbl_attendance_in join tbl_attendance_out on tbl_attendance_in.user_id=tbl_attendance_out.user_id where tbl_attendance_in.user_id=4 AND tbl_attendance_out.user_id=4 group by tbl_attendance_in.time_in,tbl_attendance_out.time_in  ;
```

this will group the duplicate rows.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work with your `GROUP BY` method. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2daf82a5c3b2612461a7b2c1c287e2af

Comment: CREATE TABLE tbl_attendance_in (
  user_id int,
  time_in datetime);
INSERT INTO tbl_attendance_in 
VALUES 
('4','2020-09-14 19:59:15'),
('3','2020-09-14 19:59:18');
  
CREATE TABLE tbl_attendance_out (
  user_id int,
  time_out datetime);
INSERT INTO tbl_attendance_out
VALUES 
('4','2020-09-14 19:59:17'),
('3','2020-09-14 19:59:19');
  
enter correct data in table

Comment: Where did you get `user_id`=3? and the timestamp value of  '2020-09-14 19:59:17'? Am I missing something here?

Comment: hi,Check nowselect tbl_attendance_in.user_id,tbl_attendance_in.time_in,tbl_attendance_out.time_out from tbl_attendance_in
inner join tbl_attendance_out on tbl_attendance_out.user_id=tbl_attendance_in.user_id